# Not able to SSH into the host machine defined in inventory file

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys

I have set up ansible on a *linux m/c running CentOS 6.4* on IP 10.65.183.37

Through this m/c i want to manage another Ubuntu-server present on host with IP 10.65.182.191

Following steps have been performed:

- created an inventory file under /tmp/my-inventory.ini 
  10.65.182.191
- it contains single host (IP above) that i need to manage

Then,I went ahead and ran following commands to ping the host ,to check connectivity is through or not.

```
 $ ansible all -i '10.65.182.191,' -c local -m ping
```

I get this as o/p

```
10.65.182.191 | success >> {
   "changed": false,
   "ping": "pong"
}
```

-c local is shorthand for --connection=local. It tells Ansible not to try to use SSH to contact the hosts, but to run tasks on our local computer instead.

Again, if i try to run 
     $ ansible all -i '10.65.182.191,' -m ping

I get this o/p

```
10.65.182.191 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.
```

Above,makes it clear that I am not using SSH to establish connection  with 10.65.182.191 host.

However,I have registered ssh-rsa key for the host 10.65.182.191 already ,and if I directly ssh into this m/c it never prompts for password.

Additionally, i'm able to ping 10.65.182.191 Ubuntu m/c from my 10.65.183.37 m/c

I'm unable to figure out the issue here .Kindly take a look and suggest what's it that i'm not following or doing wrong.

Comment: on your second `ansible -i` command, add `-vvvv`. Edit your question and add that output. I don't understand what "Above, makes it clear" means; certainly it is *attempting* to use ssh to run the ping in the second example.

Comment: it means,that eliminating the -c local parameter invokes SSH client by default,which in this case is not getting called.

Comment: still, please include the output from `-vvvv`.

Comment: <10.65.182.191> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: user
<10.65.182.191> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<10.65.182.191> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'Port=22', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=user', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.65.182.191', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible

Comment: && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1418624223.25-272938560706047'"]
10.65.182.191 | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Disabling host key checking in `~/.ssh/config` solved the problem for me:

`Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no`